# who is the administrators? extra admin user thats hidden

Tags: administrator, malware

Some of my files on win7 64bit I have found have a user called administrators not administrator.

This is a second hand laptop so Id like to know how to correct this if its a back door or something added to my laptop.

Comment: There's always an administrator account on the machine

Comment: Please provide us a screenshot (or a much better explination) of where you are seeing this. Otherwise I assume it's the usual "Administrators" _group_ that all administrator users/account belong to. If you're worried, why not just delete the user and/or reinstall Windows from scratch?

Comment: When I find a file I cannot delete or move, I go into its properties. I select the security tab, and I find the following users (system, administrator (me), and another called administrators). Once I go through the step to gain control, and switch the user control to me, I can delete it. This user administrators does not show up on the users section in control panel. Only in the properties section of specific files.

Comment: If this is a malicious user implanted into my computer Id like to find a way to remove the user in its entirety, rather than file by file.

Answer (score 2):

'Administrators' is not an user account, but representing group of 'Administrator' user account. It doesn't mean that only 'Administrator' captioned user account always be with top privilege. We can also have other user accounts as similar to be an administrator by adding them in to the 'Administrators' group.

So in your case, there could be more than one administrator account and instead adding each administrator accounts individually, someone might have used 'Administrators' to authenticate the folder in subject under Security tab. In order to verify, which are the accounts have added in to 'Administrators' group please follow this simple steps.

Press Windows + r > type devmgmt.msc > in the left pane, expand "Local Users and Groups" > on the right pane, choose 'Administrators' and double click it. Now, you will be able to see list of members of 'Administrators' group. In case, if you don't want them to be in 'Administrators' group then remove them.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the disk management window I do no have a local users and groups folder option. Thats odd... Id post a picture but dont know how here.

Comment: If you feel that, you don't want to give rights to 'Administrators' group then why don't you simply remove the group from 'Security' tab. Removing the group will not break any of your operation i guess.

Comment: I removed the administrators selection and the computer went through a long permissions change process. I still have the Administrator user present (thats my current login). So we'll see if the whole shebang dumps when I restart.

Answer (score -1):

I can't exactly answer who the account belongs to.

However, if you can access the account, you may be able to disable it if it is unnecessary. It may have user account controls that other accounts don't have, so it will be recommended to pass on these privileges and controls. Even if you have other Administrators, there's still a hierarchy.

If the account is visible, but you don't have a password to authenticate your login, I recommend a program like Konboot. In short, Konboot is a password cracker. Konboot will need to be installed onto a separate drive or partition. It's most useful to just throw Konboot onto a USB drive. Once you have it made ready, you'll need to reboot and go into your BIOS to set Konboot to boot before your user operating system.

Konboot will load. If prompted, you want to load the newest version. After a minute or so, you'll show up at your user login screen. Hit Shift 5 times, like you would do if you used sticky keys. This will allow you to open the command prompt as an Administrator.

To verify, run the command "whoami" to see if "system" shows up. If so, you've got the highest elevated privileges and that'll sure do.

Your next command will be "net user [username] /newpassword" to reset the password. This will remove it.

Logging in should be available. Detailed instructions located [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/login-to-windows-administrator-and-linux-root-account-without-knowing-or-changing-current-password/.)